# How to set leases table name created by logic app sql trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to set up a logic app workflow that will do some stuff whenever the data is inserted to a particular table in a sql db.
[image]

I read that under the hood, the mechanism used for this is the same as sql triggers for azure functions, [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1189642/how-to-configure-logic-app-ms-sql-trigger-for-buil).

When the workflow is enabled, it creates some additional tables within the sql db, to keep track of processed changes.
[image]

As you can see, there is az_func.Leases_some_ids which keeps track of Permissions table.

When I create an azure function app with those sql triggers, I'm able to specify this LeasesTableName, so it doesn't get any random numbers.

[image]

My question is, how to acheive the same result with logic app workflows?
I can't find any setting for that, I couldn't add this to the workflow json input's parameters like to azure function trigger.
[image]
If there is no straightforward solution for this, how this could be acheived?

Comment: You can call this function from logic app to get this done because logic app only accepts one  parameter

Comment: In this case, what's the point of having logic app if I can just have the azure function?
I didn't wrote the details why I need this done with logic app because it's not important

Comment: You can achieve this particular requirement with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions?tabs=standard#tabpanel_1_standard, as It is not feasible to pass the Lease TableName in logic app

Answer (score 0):

Even I have tried to take the Leases Table Name explicitly in logic app's code view but it doesn't seem to be an expected property in SQL server trigger in logic app and a lease table with random number is getting generated for me as well.

As per this [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure?tabs=standard), you can only select one parameter (database name) while creating **When a row is inserted** trigger, though under the hood both functions and logic app are using same functionality but it is a limitation in logic app that we don't get to choose the Leases table name.

[image]

If you want to give the Leases table name explicitly, then you can use azure functions or alternately you can even call the function from logic app as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions?tabs=standard#tabpanel_1_standard).

I would suggest you to raise a support/feature request with the product team to get more details about the same.